# Reviewer is requesting the use of Bonferroni adjustment to alpha in G*power calculation ("multiple regression" with 3 predictors)

Tags: bonferroni, gpower

Since Bonferroni is intended as a (conservative) adjustment to reduce Type 1 error, I'm unclear why it would be required by the reviewer to adjust alpha in the power calculation (using G*power). While making such an adjustment would increase the sample size, this is not a solution to the Type 1 error potential. Can someone provide literature justifying the reviewer's perspective in using of Bonferroni in such pre-analysis circumstances?

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  Can you provide what the reviewer wrote?

Comment: I don't have the document in hand at the moment, but in essence the Reviewer (Dissertation) insisted that the alpha in G*power calculation be adjusted by Bonferroni. I'm guessing by your comment, that I should probably ask the reviewer for clarification for this request.

Comment: Yes, clarification should be obtained.  If there are not multiple comparisons, I don't really understand the criticism.

Comment: Aren't the multiple comparisons already accounted for in G*power as it pertains to Power (Type II)? There are 3 predictors (+ 2 controls), but the alpha adjustment at this phase would only impact the sample size estimation, not Type I. Correct?

Comment: If you report the $p$-value for each regressor, you are in fact creating 3 inferences. You could just replace them with the CIs.

Comment: @AdamO Ok, yes, but it doesn't sound like OP is making multiple inferences if ⅔ of the covariates are for adjustment.

Comment: @DemetriPananos OP's question is a bit of a missing data question. If the reviewer is asking for a retrospective power analysis, well this is going badly either way. But in general, when you show a table of regression output, you need to remember, R doesn't know which regressors you care about. It's up to you to ensure that your presentation is concise. If OP cares about X but has adjusted U and V, then I would prefer to show the "X" relationship and footnote the table that U and V were adjusted for.

Answer (score 0):

It's no harder than resetting the $\alpha$ level in your G*power calculation.

When you calculate power, you have to enter the alpha level to which you're comparing the $p$-value to declare a result statistically significant. To the reviewer's comment, if you're running 10 tests and the overall $\alpha$ level is $0.05$, then for any given particular power analysis, you would set the alpha level to $0.05/10 = 0.005$.

Comment: Hmmm.....it makes sense to me (not being a statistician) that one would adjust alpha (as you've done above) in the actual analysis phase so that the interpretation of the p-value is cautiously characterized (i.e. Type 1 error), but using an adjustment in the power calculation phase only affects sample size...which has not impact on Type 1 (which is the reason for using Bonferroni in the first place). correct?

Comment: @JGates you are putting the proverbial cart before the horse. In order to calculate the sample size, you need to know the effect, desired power, variability, and alpha level. If there is going to be more than one *planned* test, then adjust alpha accordingly. Testing that is done after the primary analysis is conducted can't be interpreted as "tests" in the traditional sense, so if you decide on the number of regressors based on some model selection, the inference isn't well behaved.

Comment: Still a puzzle. By adjusting twice (pre-study sample size + again at analysis) have I not theoretically over adjusted...and biased the results to more beta error?  Whereas, if I were to keep the recruitment sample at the non-adjusted size (my actually desired, and pragmatic sizing for my study -- 0.05 level--which is balanced with Type ii error potential), then I would perform an alpha-adjusted and non-adjusted analysis and report both outcomes, and allow the reader a more fully contextualized understanding.

Comment: @JGates you seem to be thinking of multiple comparisons as a post-hoc adjustment. It's not. You *plan* for multple comparisons. Post-hoc analyses are entirely exploratory, the alpha doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the time you've taken to unravel this for me.